# query on optimal datastructure

Tags: java, data-structures

I have 2d integer array(ixj) of cells simulated as ocean.

i is width and j is height.

```
private int[][] ocean = new int[j][i];
```

I will place sharks and fish by designating integers like this.

```
public final static int EMPTY = 0;

public final static int SHARK = 1;

public final static int FISH = 2;
```

15% of cells are filled with sharks.

50% of cells are filled with fish.

But I would like to also maintain hunger level of sharks only .

Hunger level of any shark will be 1 or 2 or 3 value.

So, what extra data structure should I use to maintain hunger level info.

Assume, I only know arrays and linkedlist.

Answer (score 3):

With java you should try to go for some object oriented design model.

You could define an abstract class `Fish` and subclasses `Shark` and `Herring` so `Shark` could have an attribute `hungerLevel` and a method `feed()`.

Then you can keep the information about your ocean in a 2D-array of `Fish`: `Fish[][]`.
But since your ocean might have additional responsibilities I think there should also be an `Ocean`-class to contain the array and some additional information.

Comment: Yes, I have created ocean class like this.public                 class Ocean {
 
 
 public final static int EMPTY = 0;
 public final static int SHARK = 1;
 public final static int FISH = 2;
 public final static int UNKNOWN = -1;
 
 private int width;
 private int height;
 private int[][] matrix;
 //private int[][] hungry; need to think on optimization
 private int starveTime; .....}

Comment: Yes, I have created ocean class like this.                  public class Ocean {
 
 private int width;
 private int height;
 private int[][] oceanMatrix;
 //private int[][] hungry; need to think on optimization
 private int starveTime;
 private static int timeStep = 0;
 public Ocean(int i, int j, int starveTime){
  this.width=i; this.height=j;
  this.oceanMatrix = new int[j][i];
  this.starveTime = starveTime;
  for(int col = 0; col < j; col++){
   for(int row = 0; row < i; row++){
    oceanMatrix[col][row] = EMPTY;
   }}}

Comment: piet , did i answer your question?

Comment: i think my question has something to do with data structures rather than java

Comment: @user3265048 and piet gave you the data structures you need.

Comment: Object-orientation means thinking in bigger terms than mere "data structures" and some problems will just disappear with the right design. It's the oceans responsibility to know where the fish are, but to know wether a given shark is hungry doesn't matter to the ocean, it's just a concern of the shark. So the ocean-object keeps the oceans data (where are the fish and the sharks), the shark-object keeps the shark's data (how hungry it is).